# How to override Intervention\Image\Image method save()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controllers, intervention, laravel-4.2

I have a Model called "Image", and in my controller, i have to insert in my table some data :

```
//Insert into table 'images'
$image = new Image();
$image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
$image->vps_image_id = $img_vps_id;
$image->size = $file->getSize();
$image->save();
```

I instencie the right class "Model\Image" but when i want to save my fields, Laravel takes the Intervention\Image\Image instead of Eloquent..

So i've got this error

> Can't write image data to path

Because he want upload an inexistent file. so my question is : How to override this method ?

Comment: with an `use` statement at the top of your file.

Comment: Are you a hundred percent sure that you instantiate the overriden class?

Comment: @ThomasMoors I put this `use App\Models\Image;` at the top but Laravel can't find it

Comment: What is the namespace defined in Image.php than?

Comment: @NicoHaase Maybe PHPStorm got the illusion that I use my model because he can autocomplete with methods existing in Model\Image.php

Comment: @ThomasMoors I don't have any namespace :s

Comment: Well there is you problem, put `namespace App\Models;` there

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is with the `use` statement. You probably think it references the (relative) path to the file (altough that is also a requirement to **also** do in PSR-4). However from the comments it appears your forgot to declare the namespace of your Model. So put `namespace App\Models;` at the top of the model.

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

class Image extends Model {
...
```

Comment: I think we don't have the same version of Laravel, in 4.2, i've never seen in the documentation any namespace in Model. But i've tried to put thoses lines : no effect, i've got the error `Class 'App\Models\Image' not found ` (This path exists, i'm sure)